# How fine of grain size will it take to cover a football field?

Tags: physical-constants

There is a claim in health circles that a single Tablespoon of Bentonite clay has enough surface area to cover a football field.  Let's assume a heaping tablespoon.  If you halve a (roughly spherical) radius you get 4x the surface area, so clearly, there is SOME size that will cover the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a football field is 5300 m^2 and the surface area of bentonite is 300m^2 per gram. it therefore takes 17.6 g to cover a football field. at 2.8 g/cc, this is 6.3cc of bentonite which equals 1.3 teaspoons (not tablespoons!).

Comment: Amazing and unintuitive.  But you were able to calculate it faster and more accurately than me (if the paper is correct).

Comment: the algebra is simple (lucky for me!)   ;-) NN

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the clay is composed of uniform spheres of radius $r$. Putting them side by side to cover a field of area $A$ requires $N=A/(2r)^2$ spheres, that together have volume $V=N(4\pi r^3/3)=\pi A r/3$, or if we turn it around, $r=3V/(\pi A)$.

So for $A=5300$ m$^2$ and $V=15$ ml I get $r=2.7\cdot 10^{-9}$ m. Clay has grain sizes below $\sim 2 \mu$m and [nanometer-sized particles are common](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/clay-minerals/article/physical-dimensions-of-fundamental-clay-particles/033BC96F58EAC0E82EF2DB02AD9E5B97), so this doesn't sound too unreasonable. Since the particles are actually disk-shaped rather than spherical (giving a better covering than spheres) I think the health circle claim is true, it is just that it is likely true for most fine clays.

Answer (score 1):

Bentonite is an aluminosilicate that has a layered structure. Have a look at this picture of the structure [from a ResearchGate article](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Structure-of-bentonite-clay_fig4_304996611):

[image: Bentonite]

The bonds between the layers are weak because they are only Van der Waals bonds not chemical bonds, so the layers can come apart in a process known as *delamination*. This means the surface area of a teaspoon of bentonite is not just the surface area of the blob on the spoon. In effect you have a teaspoon of tiny platelets and the total surface area is the sum of the surface areas of all those platelets. This is the basis for the claim that a teaspoon of bentonite has a huge surface area.

In practice the surface area depends on how the bentonite has been processed. Natural bentonite only partially delaminates so its surface area is not as high as it could be. Synthentic montmorillonite clays can be made that completely delaminate. However bentonites have the benefit that they can be dug out of the ground while synthetic clays are relatively expensive to prepare.

Niels quotes a typical surface area for a commercial bentonite and shows that the claim that a teaspoon can cover a football field is indeed plausible. But bear in mind that the surface area can vary depending on the source of the clay and the processing it has gone through. From memory the theoretical surface area assuming complete delamination is nearer 800 m$^2$ per gram.